# check that command line input is numeric

Tags: c, cs50

I'm new to C and want to write a simple programme to be called with exactly two command line arguments (the first one being the programme's name, the second one being a string).
I have validated the *number* of arguments and now want to validate the input only contains digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
            {
                if isdigit(argv[1][i])
                {
                    printf("Success!\n");
                }
                else
                    {
                    printf("Error. Second argument can be numbers only\n");
                    return 1;
                    }    
            }
    else
        {
            printf("Error. Second argument can be numbers only\n");
            return 1;
        }
}
```

While the above code doesn't throw errors, it doesn't correctly validate the input and I can't figure out why. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot in advance and all the best

Comment: I suggest using `strtoul` instead of this

Comment: BTW, your code can't compile. Please post [mcve]

Comment: Just to be sure: beware of the dreadful CS50 `string`, it's not a string type, but merely a synonym of `char *`.

Comment: done; the formatting got rid of one "}" that caused the error. Thanks for highlighting that.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The goal of this exercise is not to produce an executable that validates the argument. The goal of this exercise is to learn how to write code for oneself that validates the argument. Using `strotoul` would not accomplish that goal. Your comment is like saying “Use a calculator” to somebody learning to do long division.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am suggesting using one standard library function with another more suited to the goal. The goal of learning the "long division" here is not specified in the question, so comments on improving the implementation are legitimate. The OP can take it or leave it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Right

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Using `strotul` is not more suited to the goal of learning how to write code **for oneself** to validate syntax. The OP is a **student** who is learning elementary concepts. Telling them to use a library routine does not help that. The use of “long division” is an analogy.

Comment: @Ivo When I said it can't compile I actually meant that your `if  isdigit...` - the condition should be parenthesized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (argc != 2)
```

must be

```
if (argc == 2)
```

---

Doing

```
if isdigit(argv[1][i])
{
  printf("Success!\n");
}
```

you will print "Success" 4 times if the number has 4 digits, better to do something like :

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
{
   if (!isdigit(argv[1][i])
   {
     printf("Error. Second argument can be numbers only\n");
     return 1;
   }    
 }
 printf("Success!\n");
 return 0;
```

---

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  if (argc == 2)
  {
    int i, n;

    for (i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
      if (!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
      {
        printf("Error. Second argument can be numbers only\n");
        return 1;
      }
    }
    printf("Success!\n");
  }
  else {
    puts("argument is missing");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
argument is missing
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out az
Error. Second argument can be numbers only
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 12
Success!
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 12a
Error. Second argument can be numbers only
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under valgrind :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out 123
==2051== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2051== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2051== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2051== Command: ./a.out 123
==2051== 
Success!
==2051== 
==2051== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2051==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2051==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==2051== 
==2051== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2051== 
==2051== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2051== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: whoops, the programme's earlier structure was different and I forgot updating it in the SO code. Thanks.

Comment: unbelievable this was the deal. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Ivo I also edited my answer to propose to move the `printf("Success!\n");` *after* the loop

Comment: @ivo also remember that strings end with terminator `\0` that is not a digit

Comment: @Ivo `length()` does not count the null character, and you do `i<n` so your code is ok about that, nothing to change

Comment: @Ivo I edited again my answer to add a full definition and execution examples

Comment: Note that `isdigit` has *undefined behavior* if called with negative `char` values (except for a negative `char` value that equals `EOF`), so it ought to be range-checked first. E.g. `if (argv[1][i] < 0 || !isdigit(argv[1][i]) { /* not a digit */`

Answer (score 1):

While you can rely on looping over the characters checking if each `isdigit()`, if your purpose is to use the numeric value the argument represents, you may as well use `strtol/strtoul` to convert the value to a `signed/unsigned` value and rely on the robust error reporting to tell you exactly what occurred during conversion and what, if any, portion of the argument was made up of non-digits.

The `strtoX` family of function(s) take a pointer to the string of digits and the address for an `endptr` as parameters (as well as the base for integer conversions). The function attempts to convert digits to a number updating `endptr` to point to the first character after the last digit successfully converted. This allows you to determine whether your argument was made up of leading digits, whether those fit within the range for the type of conversion attempted, and whether any additional characters exist after the last digit converted.

A short example explains:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for strtol */
#include <errno.h>      /* errno - for strtol validation */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *endptr;   /* end pointer for strtol */
    long l;

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate at least one argument provided */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient arguments provided.\n"
                         "usage: %s number\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    errno = 0;                          /* zero errno before call */
    l = strtol (argv[1], &endptr, 0);   /* attempt converstion to long */

    if (endptr == argv[1]) {    /* check if digits were converted */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no digits converted in '%s'.\n", endptr);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (errno) {           /* check for error in conversion */
        perror ("strtol-argv[1]");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("number provided: %ld\n", l);   /* output number */

    if (*endptr)    /* endptr not pointing to `'\0'`, chars remain */
        printf ("\nadditional characters following number: '%s'.\n", endptr);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtolarg 123456
number provided: 123456

$ ./bin/strtolarg -123456
number provided: -123456

$ ./bin/strtolarg "val=123456"
error: no digits converted in 'val=123456'.

$ ./bin/strtolarg "123456=val"
number provided: 123456

additional characters following number: '=val'.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.