# How to use fgets and strtol to check if the input is a valid integer?

Tags: c

I've tried

```
#define BUF_SIZE 256
char msg[BUF_SIZE];
printf("input? ");

while (fgets(msg,BUF_SIZE,stdin)!=NULL){
    char *next;
    int input = strol(msg, &next,10); //use strol 
    if ((end == msg) || (*end == '\0')){ //check validity here
       printf("invalid\n");
       printf("try again\n"); //type anther value
    else{
       printf("valid\n");
}
```

What's wrong with my code?
Is that the correct way to check integer input?

Comment: See the yesterday's question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653523/check-that-command-line-input-is-numeric

Comment: Don't confuse `end` and `next` ... just saying

Comment: And the if / else has two opening braces, but no closing ones. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo since the function is actually `strtol`, not `strol`

Comment: Please check your compiler errors.  There are many mistakes here.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong test and function name

```
// if ((end == msg) || (*end == '\0')){ //check validity here
if ((end == msg) || (*end !== '\0')){ //check validity here
  printf("invalid\n");
```

Better to assign to `long` or not at all

```
// int input = strol(msg, &next,10);
long input = strtol(msg, &next,10);
or 
strtol(msg, &next,10);
```

Use `errno` is one wants to also check for overflow.

```
errno = 0;
strtol(msg, &next,10);
if (errno == ERANGE) {
  puts("Overflow");
} else    
  ...
```